# Is the number of possible values of a quantum observable finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, observables, de-sitter-spacetime

Do we know, or have a theory about, whether the number of possible values any fundamental quantum property can assume upon observation is finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

Comment: Do you mean in theory? or in practice?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny if we have a way to experimentally determine this, then in practice. If not, then what our best current theory/theories predict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a credible reason to think that the number of distinct possible results from any given observation is necessarily *finite* — even in principle, not just in practice.

The reason comes from thinking about what is required in order to reconcile quantum physics with gravity in a universe that is asymptotically like de Sitter spacetime, which appears to be the case in the real world. In such a spacetime, any given observer can only "see"
(by any means whatosever) a finite portion of the universe, much like an observer outside a black hole cannot see the inside. Any such event horizon has an associated entropy, which is roughly interpreted as the (natural log of the) number of mutually orthogonal states of the unobservable part that are consistent with the observable part. The key is that this entropy is *finite*, according to the famous Bekenstein-Hawking entropy formula — here applied to the cosmological event horizon instead of to the event horizon of a black hole. If the number of mutually orthogonal possible states in the observable part of the universe is finite, then any given observation cannot have more than a finite number of distinct possible outcomes, not even in principle.

Here's an excerpt from reference 1 that relates the finite entropy of de Sitter spacetime to the finite entropy of black holes:

> Imagine an observer inside DS [de Sitter] space trying to contradict our contention by collecting as much entropy as she can. As long as she works on scales smaller than the DS radius of curvature, she can do this most efficiently by forming flat space black holes, whose entropy is bounded by their area. The black hole size is bounded by something of order the horizon size so there is no way to violate our bound. Put another way, a system with an entropy larger than the DS horizon size would simply not evolve into an AsDS [asymptotically de Sitter] spacetime...

That paper has been cited more than $300$ times, including by reference 2, which says this:

> The absence of a classical de Sitter limit [in the best-understood theories of quantum gravity] suggests that the possible values of $N$ [the exponential of the entropy]... are sporadic, rather than arising from infinite families, and that there might be only finitely many choices [all of which are finite].

That paper has been cited more than $600$ times. This is all still a work in progress, but the authors of these papers are well-respected experts in quantum gravity research, so I suppose this qualifies as mainstream physics. Reference 3, also written by one of the most well-respected experts, is a more recent example of the ongoing research in this area.

---

References:

1. Banks, *Cosmological Breaking of Supersymmetry?* (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007146)
2. Witten, *Quantum Gravity In De Sitter Space* (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106109)
3. Susskind, *Black Holes Hint Towards De Sitter-Matrix Theory* (https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01322)

Comment: Note how this is a natural follow-on of a series of results in quantum theory that strongly point toward it as suggesting it is a theory about _limited information content_: the first is Heisenberg's uncertainty limit, the second is RQFT and the Compton wavelength, and the third may be just this.It would be interesting to know if we can reconstruct quantum theory from some postulate such as "a region of space contains a finite amount of information", just as relativity can be derived by postulating an upper bound on the rate of information movement through space.

Comment: It certainly seems quite natural and elegant - you have a limit on information movement speed, and a limit on information quantity. How fast and how much. $c$ and $\hbar$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your in-depth answer! Would this also hold true (in regards to finite number of possible outcomes of any quantum experiment) if space turned out to be flat?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann In asymptotically flat spacetime (or in asymptotically anti-de Sitter spacetime), the same type of research suggests that the overall entropy is *not* finite. The entropy of a black hole is still finite, but not the entropy of the spacetime overall. It seems to be a special property of asymptotically de Sitter spacetime (accelerating expansion). The arguments are not conclusive, though, and the expert opinion might not be unanimous, so think of this as a credible possibility rather than as a definitive conclusion.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly but isn't the reason that overall entropy in flat and anti-de sitter space is not finite is that these spaces have infinite volumes (while the volume in de sitter space is finite afaik)? So, if you can follow from finite overall entropy that any one quantum experiment has a finite number of possible outcomes, it wouldn't automatically mean that infinite overall entropy (due to infinite space) would also mean infinitely many possible outcomes per quantum experiment - or do I understand this wrong?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann You're right, if we agree that observations are always limited to finite volume. They are in practice, of course, and we I think we can even argue that they are in principle, in spite of the fact that most textbooks formally refer to some operators (like the Hamiltonian) as "observables" even though they can't be measured in any finite volume. The point of my answer, though, is that de Sitter spacetime might provide a reason that is even more final, in the sense we don't need to argue with anybody about whether things like the system's total energy are truly "observable."